# Svg inside not aligning to center

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I am using react and on render, I am returning an SVG within a div. My code looks like this:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div class="myClass">
          <svg> ... </svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My CSS class looks like:

```
.myClass{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome and firefox, its IE where the svg is displayed to the left and not center aligned. Does IE need some more CSS properties to be added?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Does your svg element have width and height CSS properties or attributes? IE is picky about requiring those.

Comment: Yes, it does. It actually has the height, width and the viewBox attributes set. @Dom: IE 11

Comment: Please update your question with an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what's happening.for ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. Weirdly, IE treats the SVG like text. 
I added a center align to my CSS class and it worked.

My solution was:

```
.myClass{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is because SVG's are inline by default which is why the text-align works; adding `display: block;` or some other non-inline property would essentially be the same thing.

Comment: I had previously tried the display:block option, somehow it didn't show me any specific change.

Comment: I answered a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937467/ie-is-centering-my-svg/36937727#36937727). Hopefully that helps. If you're looking for full browser compatibility, it's good to have all the pieces you need in place (height, width, viewBox, display setting, etc.)

Comment: @chazsolo: Thank you!